# Greatest value of modulus of z

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given that the equation $z^2=3+4i$

How to find the greatest value of modulus of $z$?

And how to find the difference between the largest and the least values of art $z$?

I found the z is equal to $2+i$ and$-2-i$

Comment: $z^2 = 5(\frac35 + \frac45i)$, the number in the paranthesis is on the unit circle.  So $|z^2| = 5$, $|z| = \sqrt{5}$

Answer (score 1):

The modulus of the two square roots of a complex number is the same. For your example, you can just compute them and see. In general, write $z=r e^{i \theta}$, then $\sqrt z =\sqrt r e^{i(\theta/2 + k \pi}$. To get the difference in arguments, subtract them. You should also be able to see what it is from the square root formula.